# Script to pull product information in Google Merchant Center list section and send it to google sheet with the desired format I want it?

Tags: google-apps-script

I am utilizing the Shopify Google Shopping App from Shopify that is pushing products to a Content API in Google Merchant Center. I need to export that product information. Is there a script that can pull product information from the List section in Google Merchant Center and post it to a Google Sheet via Google App Scripts. I want to pull information and post it in the desired format in Google Sheets.

I already tried creating a script that can send to pull information but I can't post the information. There are only a few columns I want to post.

```
ID
TITLE
DESCRIPTION
PRICE
LINK
IMAGE LINK
```

So I want it to call to a specific Merchant Center that I'm already logged in to and post the information in a Google Sheet. Keep in mind I have over 300k products.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the official documentation on how to use the shopping content advanced service [1] which you can use to list the products on your merchant account, this is the example code they put for that:

```
/**
 * Lists the products for a given merchant.
 */
function productList() {
  var merchantId = 123456; // Replace this with your Merchant Center ID.
  var pageToken;
  var pageNum = 1;
  var maxResults = 10;
  do {
    var products = ShoppingContent.Products.list(merchantId, {
      pageToken: pageToken,
      maxResults: maxResults
    });
    Logger.log('Page ' + pageNum);
    if (products.resources) {
      for (var i = 0; i < products.resources.length; i++) {
        Logger.log('Item [' + i + '] ==> ' + products.resources[i]);
      }
    } else {
      Logger.log('No more products in account ' + merchantId);
    }
    pageToken = products.nextPageToken;
    pageNum++;
  } while (pageToken);
}
```

[1] https://developers.google.com/apps-script/advanced/shopping-content